# Как выгрузить DataGrid в XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, datagrid

Имеется `DataGrid`. Есть проблемы с выгрузкой содержимого в XML.

Класс для сериализации

```
[Serializable]
public class Buttons
{
    public bool VisibilityBut { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string PathImag { get; set; }

    public string PathExe { get; set; }
}
```

Если делаю сериализацию так

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Buttons));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"XML.XML", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    formatter.Serialize(fs, DataGrid1);
```

то файл создаётся пустым и возникает исключение

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Ошибка при создании документа XML." InvalidCastException`: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid" к типу "ПанельКнопок.Buttons".

А если так делаю:

```
if (DataGrid1.ItemsSource == null) return;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Buttons>));
var writer = new StreamWriter("XML.xml"); 
serializer.Serialize(writer, DataGrid1.ItemsSource as List<Buttons>); 
writer.Close();
```

то в файле создается только заголовок XML, и всё остальное пусто, путем подбора типов, решение такое.

```
ObservableCollection<ButtonEIIS> collection = null;

    private void butSaveXML_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // нажали кн. "Сохранить в XML"
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Buttons>));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"XML.XML", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, DataGrid1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Buttons>);
        }
    }
```

в XAML привязка такая

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Margin="10,171,10,52" FontSize="14" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Вид" Binding="{Binding VisBut}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Надпись на кнопке (папка подсистемы)" Binding="{Binding NameSubEIIS}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Полный путь к картинке" Binding="{Binding PathPNG}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Полный путь к запускаемому приложению" Binding="{Binding PathEXE}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема, собственно?

Comment: @vova-forum Редактируете ваш ответ (ссылка "править"), вставляете то, что написали в комментарии.

Comment: А почему `List<Buttons>`?

Comment: @vova-forum Переформуровал ваш вопрос, вынес туда все ваши усилия. Удалите, пожалуйста, ваши комментарии, так как они уже неактуальны. Всегда вызывайте `using`, как вы делали в первом случае. Также ошибка в первом случае обращает ваше внимание на то, что надо было передавать `DataGrid1.ItemsSource` вместо просто `DataGrid1`, и `typeof(List<Buttons>)` вместо `typeof(Buttons)`.

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком результат выполнения операции `DataGrid1.ItemsSource as List<Buttons>`

Comment: в DataGrid1.ItemsSource все кнопки массив

Comment: Я у вас не это спросил, выполните `var r = DataGrid1.ItemsSource as List<Buttons>;` и напишите чему r равно

Comment: null   -    потому что тип не подходит ,  я решение уже написал , выше в ответе